# Is there a config for uploading big files in Django with a progress bar on IIS?

Tags: python, django, iis, file-upload, fastcgi

I am using Django version 2.2 and IIS (Fastcgi) to create a web page to upload a big file with a progress bar. I used code from the following links:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/679/

My application works perfectly in a development environment, but in a production environment, when I watch the console browser it always returns a 'null' value, and the progreess bar is not showing, but the file uploaded on the server and returns '200'. Why? it is another config I should add on IIS or on my web?

The following code returns Null in the console:

```
def upload_progress(request):
    """
    Return JSON object with information about the progress of an upload.
    """
    progress_id = ''
    if 'X-Progress-ID' in request.GET:
        progress_id = request.GET['X-Progress-ID']
    elif 'X-Progress-ID' in request.META:
        progress_id = request.META['X-Progress-ID']
    if progress_id:
        cache_key = "%s_%s" % (request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], progress_id)
        data = cache.get(cache_key)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
    else:
        return HttpResponseServerError('Server Error: You must provide X-Progress-ID header or query param.')
```

view.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError
from django.core.cache import cache
from .forms import UploadFile
from upbar.UploadProgressbar import UploadProgressCachedHandler
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect
import json


@csrf_exempt
def upload_file(request):
    request.upload_handlers.insert(0, UploadProgressCachedHandler(request))
    return _upload_file(request)
# Create your views here.


def _upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UploadFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponse('200')
    else:
        form = UploadFile()
    return render(request, 'upbar/home.html', {'form': form})


def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open(f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)


# A view to report back on upload progress:
# 
def upload_progress(request):
    """
    Return JSON object with information about the progress of an upload.
    """
    progress_id = ''
    if 'X-Progress-ID' in request.GET:
        progress_id = request.GET['X-Progress-ID']
    elif 'X-Progress-ID' in request.META:
        progress_id = request.META['X-Progress-ID']
    if progress_id:
        cache_key = "%s_%s" % (request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], progress_id)
        data = cache.get(cache_key)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
    else:
        return HttpResponseServerError('Server Error: You must provide X-Progress-ID header or query param.')
```

setup.py:

```
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '4u%-od)a^a-=)_g_@^_v1sssv%)s@95f25oifgpixtx8!f=*7v'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'upbar.apps.UpbarConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'uploadbar.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'uploadbar.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2147483648
```

form.py:

```
from django import forms

class UploadFile(forms.Form):
    """UploadFile definition."""

    file = forms.FileField()
```

UploadProgressbar.py:

```
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import TemporaryFileUploadHandler
from django.core.cache import cache
import time


class UploadProgressCachedHandler(TemporaryFileUploadHandler):
    """
    Tracks progress for file uploads.
    The http post request must contain a header or query parameter, 'X-Progress-ID'
    which should contain a unique string to identify the upload to be tracked.
    """

    def __init__(self, request=None):
        super(UploadProgressCachedHandler, self).__init__(request)
        self.progress_id = None
        self.cache_key = None

    def handle_raw_input(self, input_data, META, content_length, boundary, encoding=None):
        self.content_length = content_length
        if 'X-Progress-ID' in self.request.GET:
            self.progress_id = self.request.GET['X-Progress-ID']
        elif 'X-Progress-ID' in self.request.META:
            self.progress_id = self.request.META['X-Progress-ID']
        if self.progress_id:
            self.cache_key = "%s_%s" % (
                self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], self.progress_id)
            cache.set(self.cache_key, {
                'length': self.content_length,
                'uploaded': 0
            }, 30)

    def new_file(self, field_name, file_name, content_type, content_length, charset=None, content_typ_extra=None):
        pass

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        if self.cache_key:
            data = cache.get(self.cache_key)
            data['uploaded'] += self.chunk_size
            cache.set(self.cache_key, data)
        return raw_data

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        if self.cache_key:
            data = cache.get(self.cache_key)
            data['uploaded'] = self.content_length
            cache.set(self.cache_key, data)
            # sleep for give time to receive final response in request progress bar
            time.sleep(3)

    def upload_complete(self):
        if self.cache_key:
            cache.delete(self.cache_key)
```

upload.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function gen_uuid() {
    var uuid = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      uuid += Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
    }
    return uuid
  }
  uuid = gen_uuid();
  // form submission
  $('form').submit(function () {
    // Prevent multiple submits
    if ($.data(this, 'submitted')) return false;
    // Append X-Progress-ID uuid form action
    this.action += (this.action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'X-Progress-ID=' + uuid;
    $('<div class="progress"> <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"> 0% </div></div>').appendTo('body')

    upload_progress_url = '/upload_progress/'

    function update_progress_info() {
      $.getJSON(upload_progress_url, {
        'X-Progress-ID': uuid
      }, function (data, status) {
        console.log(data)
        if (data) {
          var progress = Math.round((parseInt(data.uploaded) * 100) / parseInt(data.length));
          $('#progressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', progress).css('width', progress + '%').text(progress + '%');

        }

        window.setTimeout(update_progress_info, 100);
      }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log('jqxhr errorrr ==================')
        console.log(jqxhr);
        console.log('==================')
        console.log('textstatus ==================')
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log('==================')
        console.log('jqxhr.responsetext errorrr ==================')
        console.log(jqxhr.responseText)
        console.log('==================')
        console.log('errorrr ==================')
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    window.setTimeout(update_progress_info, 100);
    $.data(this, 'submitted', true); // mark form as submitted.
    return true;

  });
});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    Noting Here
    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>  

        <script src="{% static 'upbar/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'upbar/upload.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of my console browser:
 [image: console browser watch].

Answer (score 0):

You could use below options to increase the file upload limit in iis:

1) Modify the maxAllowedContentLength setting in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

2)use iis request filtering feature:

- Open IIS Manager.
- Select the website that you want to configure.
- Select Requests Filtering feature from the feature view.
- From the Actions pane on the right-hand side of the screen click Edit Feature Settings... link. The Edit Request Filtering Settings window displays.
- In the Request Limits section, enter the appropriate Maximum allowed content length (Bytes) and then click the OK button.
  [image]

3)Manually edit the ApplicationHost.config file

- Open notepad as administrator.
- Open file %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config.
- In the ApplicationHost.config file, locate the  node
- add `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength ="<length>" />`
- Save the ApplicationHost.config file.

Please do not forget to restart the iis server after doing changes.